# How to dynamically choose what inherited properties will be serialized?

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a base class with a few properties, and three deriving classes.

I want to serialize an object containing all three derived classes, but each derived class should expose a different set of properties from base class.

I want to do this dynamically with XmlAttributeOverrides and have tried a few differnt ways to do that, but nothing that really does it.

```
[Serializable]
public class A
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class B : A
{
}

[Serializable]
public class C : A
{
}

[Serializable]
public class Container
{
    public B B { get; set; }
    public C C { get; set; }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        StreamWriter encodingWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.Unicode);

        var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(encodingWriter, new XmlWriterSettings
        {
            Indent = false,
            OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
        });
        XmlAttributeOverrides overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
        XmlAttributes attribute = new XmlAttributes();
        attribute.XmlIgnore = true;
        overrides.Add(typeof(B), "Property1", attribute);
        overrides.Add(typeof(C), "Property2", attribute);
        var container = new Container
            {
                B = new B {Property1 = "B property 1", Property2 = "B property 2"},
                C = new C {Property1 = "C property 1", Property2 = "C property 2"}
            };

        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Container), overrides);
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, container);

        var result = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
    }
}
```

In the above code, the result string will contain all the properties of A in B and C, but I really want it just to contain B Property2 and C Property1 (as I have set the XmlIgnore attributes for them).

How do I do this?

EDIT: The expected XML:

```
<Container xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><B><Property2>B property 2</Property2></B><C><Property1>C property 1</Property1></C></Container>
```

The actual XML:

```
<Container xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><B><Property1>B property 1</Property1><Property2>B property 2</Property2></B><C><Property1>C property 1</Property1><Property2>C property 2</Property2></C></Container>
```

EDIT 2: The above is an example to visualize the problem, but I will expand on why we have the need to do this.

We have a Container-class (like above) which contains different kinds of derived objects (like above).
When we expose data from the Container-class to others, we want to be able to expose just certain fields which are configurable at some other place (might be sensitive data or whatnot).

This we do with help of XmlAttributeOverrides to set XmlIgnore property for the exposed properties. This works well for most types of objects (which does not have inheritance), but now we have the need to serialize different derived objects in different ways (configurable).

So in the above example, some customer has made the decision to exclude Property1 from class B and Property2 from class C, and as such I want the XML to look like above.
This did not work with the above code though; it seems like XmlSerializer uses the settings for the properties from the base class A, instead of using it from the respective derived classes B and C.

Comment: While unrelated to your question, note that the `[Serializable]` attribute is not required when using the `XmlSerializer`.

Comment: I ended up (for other reasons) serializing all parts individually (via reflection) and that solved this problem also at the same time as solving another problem. @ChrisSinclair had a descent enough solution though, so I have marked it as answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's hard to tell from your question exactly what XML output you're looking for, so I'll just throw out an example and you can modify it as you need to. (EDIT: Seems I lucked out; the sample implementations below match your edited desired XML result)

You can use the little known [`ShouldSerializePROPERTYNAME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53b8022e%28vs.71%29.aspx) method to dynamically instruct the `XmlSerializer` to ignore properties. For example:

```
public class A
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }

    public virtual bool ShouldSerializeProperty1()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public virtual bool ShouldSerializeProperty2()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

These methods can then be overridden by the subclasses to ignore those properties:

```
public class B : A
{
    public override bool ShouldSerializeProperty1()
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public class C : A
{
    public override bool ShouldSerializeProperty2()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Similarly, you can control the return values of the methods via other properties which can be assigned by `Container`:

```
public class A
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    internal bool _ShouldSerializeProperty1 = true;
    [XmlIgnore]
    internal bool _ShouldSerializeProperty2 = true;

    public bool ShouldSerializeProperty1()
    {
        return _ShouldSerializeProperty1;
    }

    public bool ShouldSerializeProperty2()
    {
        return _ShouldSerializeProperty2;
    }
}
```

Then when assigning `B` and `C` to `Container`, you can set those flags:

```
public class Container
{
    private B _B;
    public B B 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _B;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                value._ShouldSerializeProperty1 = false;
                value._ShouldSerializeProperty2 = true;
            }
            _B = value;
        }
    }

    private C _C;
    public C C
    {
        get
        {
            return _C;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                value._ShouldSerializeProperty1 = true;
                value._ShouldSerializeProperty2 = false;
            }
            _C = value;
        }
    }
}
```

These are just some examples (and I don't claim to have used best practices here) to demonstrate how `ShouldSerialize` can be used. You'll probably want to adapt it however best to your particular usage.

EDIT: Given your updated post, there's another possibility but requires a bit of extra work defining your subclasses and some DRY violation (though for serialization, sometimes that's ok).

First define `A`'s properties as `virtual` and override them in the subclasses as basic wrappers:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual string Property1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override string Property1 { get { return base.Property1; } set { base.Property1 = value; } }
    public override string Property2 { get { return base.Property2; } set { base.Property2 = value; } }
}

public class C : A
{
    public override string Property1 { get { return base.Property1; } set { base.Property1 = value; } }
    public override string Property2 { get { return base.Property2; } set { base.Property2 = value; } }
}
```

Then since (I'm assuming) you're managing/building your `XmlSerializer` serialization via those configurations, include `XmlIgnore` overrides for *all* of the *base class's properties*:

```
overrides.Add(typeof(A), "Property1", attribute);
overrides.Add(typeof(A), "Property2", attribute);
```

Then *also* include `XmlIgnore` overrides for the *subclass* properties that you wish to *truly* ignore:

```
overrides.Add(typeof(B), "Property2", attribute);
overrides.Add(typeof(C), "Property1", attribute);
```

This will produce your desired output.

Comment: I have edited the question with the expected XML. My feeling is that there should be a much more easy solution than decorating with lots of specific ShouldSerialize properties. The provided code is an example which caught the problem, my actual code uses lots more generic code with reflection and stuff to figure out what properties should be serialized and not.

Comment: @Joel: Well, what you're doing is _generally_ outside the common use-case scenarios for XML serialization so it's unsurprising that it's "not easy". _Ideally_, you want your data model to be fixed and have your C# classes match 1-to-1 with your XML schema. Your application code should be abstracted from your XML serialization code so you don't have to perform tomfoolery like this. (Yes, that might mean you might have a specific `Container_B` and `Container_C` classes, plausibly without deriving from a common `A` class. Then convert to/from these when working with your application logic.)

Comment: Just to expand, if you're using reflection and "stuff" to figure out what properties should be serialized, it may be hard to comment on a best solution to your problem. The best advice I can give (and it may not even be applicable) is to abstract your application logic from your serialization concerns as much as possible. Keep your data serialization layer _simple_ or it will just lead to headaches (like now) or later on when trying to change/update your schema.

Comment: I have added extra information in the original post, I hope the need is better described, and I will continue provide more information if needed. :)

Comment: @Joel: I'm getting a better picture. Unfortunately, I've also tried dabbling into using inheritance to control how properties are formatted to/from XML years ago. Honestly, I don't remember specifics (if they work with overriding or with hiding, or if you use `XmlSerializers` based on the base class or subclass, etc.) but I came to the conclusion to avoid it. However, I hacked a way around it so you can pull it off, see my edit to my answer.

Comment: I actually arrived at a similar solution as you at one point, but I thought it was a bit ugly and it hides some of the advantages with inheritance, since I have to declare the properties all over again. But I suppose that will have to do if noone else comes up with a more elegant solution. :)

Comment: Although this was not the final solution I went with, I will still mark it as the answer, since it was the closest to it. :)